# Is it possible to auto-update install4j bundled JRE

Tags: java, install4j

I've got an install4j question.

I was wondering if it is possible to update the bundled JRE of an application that is already installed.

For example, in our application we had a bundled java 6. Now, we upped the minimum version to java 7 and we bundle JRE 8.
For new installations this works fine. But with existing installs, but JRE 8 is not downloaded in the update process, and after updating the application gives an error at startup:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: camMan/shared/E/p : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at camMan.c.b.s.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at camMan.unsecure.LoginLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using install4j version 5.1.15.
- We use a dynamic bundle (download on demand)
- "install as a shared JRE" is disabled
- "install only if no other suitable JRE is found" is enabled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt it. Just have the users update their Java environment instead of attempting to control theirs

Comment: In principle this should work. Please run the new installer with the 1.7 minimum version from the command line with the argument `/create-i4j-log` and send the log file to support@ej-technologies.com

Comment: You are right Ingo, I was looking in the complete wrong direction with this issue. The update of the bundled java works flawlessly. The problem was that we used some libraries in the application that were built with target java 8, which gave an error for users that had bundled java 7 (as I should have gathered from "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0"). We recompiled the libraries and solved it. Sorry for wasting your time!